# override FieldPluginBase init function Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

is it possible to inject a custom service into a class which extends FieldPluginBase ?

```html
  public function init(ViewExecutable $view, DisplayPluginBase $display, array &$options = NULL) {
    parent::init($view, $display, $options);
    $this->currentDisplay = $view->current_display;
  }
```

When I try to inject one of my services I get that error :

> Fatal error: Declaration of Drupal\xxx_api\Plugin\views\field\NewsViewsField::init(Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view, Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase $display, ?array &$options, Drupal\xxx_api\Service\ArticleService $articleService) must be compatible with Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase::init(Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view, Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase $display, ?array &$options = NULL)

Thanks by advance for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, but you should inject it either in the constructor or via the `create()` method.

In the same `views` core module of which you are extending the `FieldPluginBase` class from there is a `RenderedEntity` class which is a good example that does so.

So in your case this could look like something in the below. Note that I have used `YourService` as a placeholder for the service that you are trying to inject:

```
namespace Drupal\xxx_api\Plugin\views\field;

/**
 * Example Views field.
 *
 * @ViewsField("news_views_field")
 */
class NewsViewsField extends FieldPluginBase {

  /**
   * Your Service interface.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\foo\YourServiceInterface
   */
  protected $yourService;

  /**
   * Constructs a NewsViewsField object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\foo\YourServiceInterface $your_service
   *   Your Service.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, YourServiceInterface $your_service) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    // Inject your service.
    $this->yourService = $your_service;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      // Add your service here to pass an instance to the constructor.
      $container->get('your.service')
    );
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for ! :)